Is a low energy transfer straight to the L1 earth-moon lagrange point more delta-v intensive than a ballistic capture?
Going from Low Earth orbit to Lunar orbit, all missions I came across that used a low energy transfer (GRAIL,CAPSTONE,SLIM to name a few) first went out to the Earth-Sun L1 lagrange point, and then performed a ballistic capture to lunar orbit. I assume the Lunar orbit insertion would cost too much delta-v if a low energy transfer to the Earth-Moon L1 (spacecraft remaining closer to Earth than the orbit of the moon) was performed instead, because the velocity coming into the Moon sphere of influence would be large.
Im not sure if my assumption is correct and if the low energy transfer to the L1 point is more delta-v intensive, how much more delta-v would be needed to perform it?
